# Shukra Neeti in Mahabharta and Ramayana?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, dharma-shastras

Is Shukra Niti a real text if so, was it used to govern Ram Rajyam or kingdoms in Mahabharata? If not is it mentioned if so how. Is this a good substitute for Dharmashastras? I am confused. Are their other Neetis?

Comment: @Narasimham I am more interested in the scripture than the author in regards to ithihasas and what exactly is it.

Comment: OK deleting it.